# Was the LEGO flower petal redesigned?

Tags: piece-information, annual-support

I noticed part [24866](https://rebrickable.com/parts/24866/flower-1x1/30/) in one of our sets from TLG:

[image: 24866]

This looks a bit different to me. Has this part been redesigned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit of research, it looks like this is a new part for 2018.

The part that it is likely replacing is the [old flower petal](https://rebrickable.com/parts/33291/plate-round-1-x-1-with-flower-edge-4-petals/) with stud connections:

Old:[image: old petal] New:[image: new part]

The new part has 5 petals instead of 4, and they are shorter so that they don't collide with neighboring parts at any angle. New Elementary did a [writeup on the new flower parts](http://www.newelementary.com/2017/12/new-2018-lego-flower-24866-plant-leaf-32607.html) that includes an image to highlight this:

[image: old vs new spacing]

Both parts include the interior flower stem connector so that they can be used with either the new or recently redesigned flower stem.

Comment: It looks good from above but bad from all other angles. The petals simply aren't proportional to the plate height, which is a shame. IMO the trade-off in favor of functionality is rather poor.

Comment: I see your point. They look particularly stubby when compared to the original flower petal.

Comment: On the bright side, having more flower molds means you can mix and match them to create more diverse gardens and even bouquets :)